# margin-top: auto; not working for a flex child

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to push the footer, inside a flex, to page end. I'm using `margin-top: auto` to accomplish the same, but it doesn't work. I also tried `align-self` and `align-items`, they don't work as well. I also looked at all the SOs. What am I missing?

Codepen for my problem: https://codepen.io/vivekest/pen/XWmvyKq

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you expect `margin-top: auto` to do? AFAIK it's the same as `margin-top: 0`. To position  the footer at the bottom, it's probably better to use `display: grid`.

Comment: I expect it to pull the content to the bottom of parent. Is there anything else `margin-top: auto` is used for? It's not the same as `margin-top: 0` Thanks for your `display: grid` suggestion, but I will go with Yousaf's solution :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `height` on `#all-content`

```
#all-content{
  ...
  height: 100vh;
}
```

another approach is to set `justify-content` property on `#all-content` and remove `margin-top` from `#page-footer`

```
#all-content{
  ...
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100vh;
}

#page-footer{
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I had tried by setting the height:100%. Didn't know there's a difference between height:100% and height: 100vh! Thanks!

Comment: `height: 100%` means 100% height of the parent element's height and `height: 100vh` means height of the viewport

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that there is nothing between the footer and the all-content and hence the page-footer was not going down, so the usual way is to make a div block and set it's height to 100vh and it will be useful when you want to add more content between these two or

you can set margin-top:100vh that will bring the page-footer block down.

and yes stating the height is also a great method.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem but new approach:

```
.fix-footer-on-card-bottom{

     position: absolute;
     bottom: 0;
     display: block;
     width: 100%;}
```

you card add this class (fix-footer-on-card-bottom) to the footer.